# MVC3 multiple tabs returning partial view with different data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-tabs

I have few tabs in my view and have a partial view.

Partial view contains a web grid. Depending on the selected tab grid has to be loaded with specific data.

Using RenderAction to return partial view. But I am getting overflow exception when I post my view.

This is my code.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Sage Pay</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" >Pay Pal</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        @{Html.RenderAction("SagePayPayments", "OrderProcessing");}
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @{Html.RenderAction("PayPalPayments", "OrderProcessing");}
    </div>
```

And my controller is

```
public ActionResult PayPalPayments()
    {
        var model = new OrderContext().GetNewPayments(PaymentType.PayPal);
        return PartialView("_PaymentsToVerify", model);
    }

    public ActionResult SagePayPayments()
    {
        var model = new OrderContext().GetNewPayments(PaymentType.SagePay);
        return PartialView("_PaymentsToVerify", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult VerifyPayments(FormCollection formData)
    {
        var context = new OrderContext();
        var orderIds = formData.GetValues("chkSelected");
        if (orderIds != null)
        {
            IList<long> selectedOrders = orderIds.Select(orderId => Convert.ToInt64(orderId)).ToList();
            context.VerifyPayments(selectedOrders);
        }
        return View("Unverified");
    }
```

Can somebody help me what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: What does the partial view (_PaymentsToVerify) looks like ?

Comment: Partial view has a webgrid. Just binding grid with model.

Comment: What is the name of the view/action you have pasted here? And what is the piece of code that produces the overflow? Maybe you have a recursive view? (ie a view that tries to render a partial view that contains a render of the parent view)

Answer (score 0):

We seemed to have focused on views in this issue, but I doubt it is the problem.

You are convrrting a value to a long, this could throw an overflow exception if it evaluates to a value that exceed long.MaxValue or to less than long.MinValue.

I'd say, put this bit in a try catch block and try to run your code again, then check what is the value you are trying to convert and somve the real issue from there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is not typecat exception. It is overflow exception.

Comment: Here, if you cast it from a string it can throw an overflow exception.
If it was a problem with the view, like unwanted infinite recursion it would be a StackOverflow Exception. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zahhahw.aspx